# Change DB State with an Submit Button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want add to my Laravel 5 Website and Button where change the value after submit.

Here my Example code:

```
<form method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="{{$sale->state}}">
 <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">FE</button>
</form>
```

Dont work but i just playing a little bit. Any one an good Idea how can make this Action?

I want that the Button click make an change from Status `delivered` to `complete` = In my DB Table `sale` and `state` must change the state value from 1 to 3.

Many Thanks

Comment: Your `<input>`'s field `name` attribute should be `status`, (or `state` maybe?) and you should send the value to the server to handle; not sure what you're trying to do by setting the `name` attribute to a variable value...

Comment: Any Link or example? Your comment dont helped me.

Comment: Please post your route and your controller method

Comment: Where are you POSTing to?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your `input` must be the name of the model attribute (that reflects in database table column).

Try this (if your column name is `state`):

`<input type="hidden" value="3" name="state">`

By using `name="{{$sale->state}}"` as `name` attribute, you're passing the value of `state` attribute from your `$sale` object.